# Listing caption numbers are reverse in the list of listings

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, captions, bidi, xepersian

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{FreeFarsi}% http://sourceforge.net/projects/fpf/
\DefaultMathsDigits

\lstdefinestyle{C++Style}{%
  breaklines=true,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  frame=single,
  language =  C++,
  captiondirection=RTL,
}

\lstnewenvironment{C++Code}[1][]
{
   \lstset{style=C++Style, #1}
}{}

\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings

\chapter{firstChapter}
\section{firstSection}

\begin{LTR}
\begin{C++Code}[caption={تابع فلان}]
int main()
{
  return 0;
}
\end{C++Code}
\end{LTR}

\section{secondSection}
\begin{LTR}
\begin{C++Code}[caption={تابع بهمان}]
int main()
{
  return 0;
}
\end{C++Code}
\end{LTR}

\end{document}
```

The captions are generated correctly:

[image: Listings]

But, as you can see, in the TOC, the numbers are LTR-oriented (instead of RTL).

[image: List of Listings]

How can I get it right?

I must mention that I did not have such a problem with `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`. Apparently, `\lstlistoflistings` was *implemented* differently (in the `bidi` package which is used by `xepersian`).

Comment: How and where in the `bidi` package, `\lstlistoflistings` is implemented? (let alone differently!). Being the author of `bidi` package myself, your claim sound too strong!

Comment: You are right. I meant "dealt with" rather than "implemented". There is something you did for `\listoffigures` you didn't do for `\lstlistoflistings`.

Comment: I have uploaded v16.6 of `bidi` package to CTAN which should fix this. In future, please do not use forums like this to report issues; instead, please file a bug report: https://github.com/persian-tex

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a report of a bug which has since been fixed by the package author.